# Can the SSMS editor be re-used in your own application, or is there an alternative?

Tags: sql, intellisense, ssms

I would like to have IntelliSence or code completion, and syntax highlighting for SQL queries in my own .NET application.

1. Is it possible to use the SQL Server Management Studio's editor similar to the way you can use the SMO APIs?
2. Are there open source control(s) that can be used?

I have found code completion / syntax highlighting controls, but SQL is a funny beast because of the column / table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. It is not possible to use SQL Server Management Studio's editor in your own application.
2. [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) is an open-source alternative that [supports MS Flavoured TSQL](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToSyntax) (and Postgre SQL) highlighting out of the box.